# Submitting for App Store in 4.2: Strange "Whitespace" error from XCode submission validation

Tags: iphone, xcode, submission, app-store, ios-4.2

I originally submitted and was approved with the 4.1 SDK.  I upgraded to the 4.2 and was making some fixes, and when I tried to submit to the App Store I got this message:

"Filename may not contain whitespace."

My info.plist had the default ${Executable} as the Executable File property.  I went ahead and changed it.  Tried rebuilding, and got the same error. Strange thing though, the filename that XCode was assigning was a match to my "Bundle Display Name," which is what controls how the app is named in Springboard.  I changed the Bundle Display Name property to have No_Spaces, and the app passed validation.

I don't really want my app to have an underscore in the name, so I'm wondering if this is a bug or if I missed something somewhere.  Keep in mind that NOTHING other than some code tweaks changed between submission and approval in 4.1, and submitting in 4.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this Thread:

https://devforums.apple.com/message/282652#282652

Known problem with XCode 3.2.5

Answer (score 0):

Change the Product Name in the Distribution Build Settings for your app's Target, and remove spaces from that name.  It's one of 5 "names" for an app (Target name, Product Name, Bundle display name, Bundle Identifier, iTunes store name), which can all be different.  You can still have spaces in your iTunes name and the under-the-icon Bundle display name.